# Are there any alternatives to pidof? (smaller footprint)

Tags: process, cpu, alternatives, pidof

Well, I've just found out that with extensive usage of `pidof` in **very short intervals**, the seemingly tiny tool can be a great **CPU hog**. (Source: `top`)
On my older machine, it can easily reach 30 percent peaks especially in batch usage, though only for a short time, but I think that for a simple task like finding the PID of a process, the footprint of such tool should be one fifth of `pidof`'s (if at all).

That is also why I wonder if it might be more sensible to "construct" the finding of the process ID with built-in standard tools. It would not be surprising to me if the *sum* of CPU load caused by executing the whole pipe managed to stay *below* the load caused by running `pidof` standalone.

Furthermore, it would be interesting to know *what* is causing these high peaks. Maybe there is even somebody here amongst you guys who has dug a little deeper into the `pidof` code? :)

Comment: How do you use `pidof` command? Is it something like `pidof firefox`?

Comment: Well, you could use `lsof -c firefox` to list all files opened by a particular command. It lists the pids as well. So it could be tweaked as a smaller footprint.

Comment: It would be _very_ surprising to me if you could get it better than pidof. Anyway, please tell us how exactly you are using `pidof` and bear in mind that a high CPU usage is not necessarily a bad thing. It is only a problem if you don't have enough to go around. Do these spikes also happen when that 30% would make a difference? Finally, and most importantly, if you are running it repeatedly, presumably via a bash loop, it is almost certainly bash and not pidof itself that is causing the spike.

Comment: If using `pidof` gets you up to 30% it's definitely not the tool. All it does is read `/proc/%s/exe` and that's about as lightweight as you can get.

Comment: @Ramesh yes, like `$(pidof firefox)` in a `bash` script, for instance. @terdon `bash` might indeed be the actual culprit, yes. However that's merely speculating. :) BTW, it's just that I think such easy task *ought not* produce these spikes. Whether there is still some air to breathe for my CPU or not, does not matter here.

Comment: How long does it peak at 30% for? Just the process of loading the program could cause a spike. You could compare with something like `/bin/true` to check this (be sure to use the actual program though and not a shell builtin).

Comment: Thanks for the `true` tip. (Instead of prefixing the path, `env true` should do the trick.) Peaks are usually short, as I wrote in the OP. But considering that `pidof` might be executed *several times* per one second, lots of high peaks can be significant as well.

Comment: Just asked a related question which you may find useful - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163681/print-pids-and-names-of-processes-as-they-are-created

Comment: pidof takes a fraction of a second to run, but during that time it isn't doing any sleeping, it's either using the CPU or reading in-memory files. So if you happen to catch it with ps or top, it will appear to be using a high percentage of CPU time. As for an alternative, it depends what problem you're trying to solve. It's simpler to have the target process write its PID to a file in a known place, such as /var/run, if you can.

Comment: ... and read it out. That's a good approach, even though I'm always so reluctant with using temp files. In fact, your method is not much different from that of a computer graphics artist who reads off a sine table for periodically repeating values instead of *computing* the "live" sine several thousand times per minute. It's closer to the matter than you think: running `pidof` an uncountable number of times even though the PID might be still unchanged is pretty much the same thing. Thank you very much, I think I *will* (albeit reluctantly) try to use a temp file.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples to find pids of processes named "apache2".  There are minor differences (newlines in output) between these and `pidof` but otherwise ought to work the same, in pipelines, etc.

Using `pidof`:

```
$ pidof apache2
31751 31750 31749 31748 31747 31489 31488 31487 31486 31485 1500
```

Newline-separated:

```
$ ps aux | grep apache2 | grep -v grep | awk -n '{print $2}'
1500 
31485 
31486 
31487 
31488 
31489 
31747 
31748 
31749 
31750 
31751
```

Space-separated:

```
$ ps aux | grep apache2 | grep -v grep | awk -n '{printf $2" "}'
1500 31485 31486 31487 31488 31489 31747 31748 31749 31750 31751
```

I did some silly timings of the above commands.

```
$ date +%T:%N; pidof apache2 ;  date +%T:%N
17:06:05:627088798
31751 31750 31749 31748 31747 31489 31488 31487 31486 31485 1500
17:06:05:634500908

$ date +%T:%N; ps aux | grep apache2 | grep -v grep | awk -n '{printf $2" "}' ;  date +%T:%N
17:06:29:887314682
1500 31485 31486 31487 31488 31489 31747 31748 31749 31750 31751
17:06:29:903997288
```

pidof: 7,412,110 nanoseconds

ps | grep | awk : 16,682,606 nanoseconds

On my machine, `pidof` is loads faster (as expected).

The output of `pidof` seems to be sorted reverse, so this would be my preferred alternative incantation:

```
$ ps aux | grep apache2 | grep -v grep | awk -n '{print $2}' | sort -rn
31751
31750
31749
31748
31747
31489
31488
31487
31486
31485
1500
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it is weird that `pidof` is spiking to 30%. But if it's just a temporary spike would that be such a bad thing?

Alternatively you could use `ps(1)`. Example:

```
$ ps ax | grep firefox
8621 ??  S       5:20.24 firefox
10409 p3  R+      0:00.00 grep firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a set of command to manage processes (pgrep, pkill, etc.); so, the best option is (for macOSX):

```
$ ps -ef | pgrep login
102
103
6245
6361
```

... or, in reverse order:

```
$ ps -ef | pgrep login | sort -rn
6361
6245
103
102
```

... or, the last one:

```
$ ps -ef | pgrep login | sort -rn | head -n 1
6361
```

Comment: You don't need the initial `ps -ef`: `pgrep` already scans the process list on its own, so your examples are doing it twice.